# Several TypeScript Errors on Atom when there is none

Tags: javascript, typescript, atom-editor

I installed Atom 1.16.0 and added several packages including the

> typescript-atom

package to use it to compile TypeScript files.

I initialized the tsc project with:

```
$tsc -init
```

In order to use it with Atom and the package. There are moments when the linter and the autocompile feature, messes up and shows a lot of errors that simply doesn't exist.

The way I can replicate it is to start writing a bad syntax and save it that way, when it happens the entire IDE shows a lot of errors.

This is the TypeScript:

```
let spiderman ={
  name:"test",
  power:true
}

spiderman = {
  name:"test",
  power:false
}

let texto:string = `Hello this is strange`;

let message = `This is even stranger ${spiderman}`;

let texto3 = "test";
```

This are the errors that shows the linter and the TypeScript

```
Severity    Provider    Description Line 
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto'. 12:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto'. 14:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot find name 'sg'.  14:11
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto'. 16:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto'. 18:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto'. 20:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto'. 22:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto'. 24:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto'. 26:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto'. 28:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto'. 30:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto'. 32:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'message'.   34:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto3'.    36:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'message'.   38:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto3'.    40:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'message'.   42:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto3'.    44:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'message'.   46:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto3'.    48:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'message'.   50:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto3'.    52:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'message'.   54:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto3'.    56:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'message'.   58:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto3'.    60:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'message'.   62:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto3'.    64:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'message'.   66:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto3'.    68:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'message'.   70:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto3'.    72:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'message'.   74:5
Error   Typescript  Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'texto3'.    76:5
```

I don't know if this anything but normal, does anyone had the same issue with Atom and TypeScript?